# What happens to my older posts if I switch to a child theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme

I have a theme that has one custom post type. I want to mess with its templates and styles.css file. What happens to my older custom posts in case I switch to using the child theme. Do they vanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing would happen, everything would remain the same. Child themes inherit the functionality of the parent theme.

Just a few notes

- All posts regardless of post type is stored in db, so they never "disappear" even when the post type does not exist anymore.
- Custom post types and custom taxonomies **should** be registered in a plugin to keep them available even when you change themes